# How do I get the content (mostly images) to scale or resize with the window size on tumblr?

Tags: html, css, image, scale, tumblr

My blog/website is iamdonle.com
An example of what I want is 13thwitness.com
The images on mine doesn't scale and a scroll bar will appear. On his website the images get smaller with the window. I'm sure it's simple but I'm a noob. Please help!

Comment: The trick is to do `img { max-width:100%; height:auto}`, but it looks like your main images are already scaling down when you shrink the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

You images are scaling down, but your logo is not!

Try:

```
.logo {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to make sure your container is able to scale. Right now it has a set width of `1150px`, this needs to be either a max-width *or* percentage based.

First, remove the width declared on `#container` and add this CSS:

```
#container {
  max-width: 1150px;
  padding: 5px 30px 0;
}
```

Then you'll need to *remove* the width declared for your header. You can do this by either removing the line completely (line 82 of your CSS file) or by overriding it in your 'Custom CSS' field box in the Customization screen by doing:

```
#header {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Then, as others have mentioned, you'll need to add a max-width to your logo as well.

```
#header img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Note: when I viewed the blog you were using the "Quite Big" theme, the code above only applies to that theme.